# How to Saving multiple layer at once to png in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, png, photoshop-scripting

Can able to find the way to saving multiple layer in photoshop and with same Names to be saving in one folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use File>>Export>>Layers to files...

Change the directory and extension file.

each layer will be saved separately.

See the image below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much leonas, with the same layer names it will saving leonas ?!

Comment: Leonas I want With Same layer Name Should be saving in one folder ?

Comment: In **export Layers To Files** dialog, delete the **File Name Prefix**.